# Mount component into DOM with JS in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm making a GUI for a webgame with Vue.JS, now I'm using [http-vue-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) to avoid using Webpack and similar (sorry but I really hate it).

Now, usually what I do for get my component into my DOM is this:

**GUI.js**

```
    // Creating Vue.js istance for GUI
    Pixua.GUI = new Vue({
      el: '#GUI',
      components: {
        'Debug': httpVueLoader('./gui/windows/Debug.vue')
      },
      data: {
        row: 0,
        column: 0
      }
    });
```

**Index.html**

```
<div id="GUI">
      <windows id="windows">
           <debug v-bind:row="row" v-bind:column="column" ></debug>
      </windows>
</div>
```

**Debug.vue** (it's my component)

```
<template>
  <px-window title="Debug" :width="200" :is-open.sync="isOpen">
      Casella cliccata:
      <ul>
        <li>Riga: {{row}}</li>
        <li>Colonna: {{column}}</li>
      </ul>
  </px-window>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    props: ['row','column'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            isOpen: true
        }
    }
}

</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Now my question is: is possible to get the component mounted/rendered into the DOM dinamically with JS (via GUI.js) and without specifying it into the index.html (so without `<debug v-bind:row="row" v-bind:column="column" ></debug>`)?

Comment: Your debug component uses  a `px-window` component, but this is not declared as a component nor imported. Maybe your issue is related to this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I also use vue-window component: https://github.com/michitaro/vue-window (px-window is from this component).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

```
<component v-bind:is="myComponent"></component>
```

And then change the value of myComponent to the component you want to load.

```
data() {
    return {
        myComponent: 'debug'
    }
}
```

Will render the debug component

Comment: Already checked this, but I'm making a GUI based on a Window System (so I can have many Windows opened at the same time), what I want to avoid is to have to insert them all into the Index.html.

Another problem is that this is a multiplayer game with Client-Server architecture, where I need to generate a not known number of windows with text sent by the Server, so I doesn't know how many windows I could need.

Comment: it seems that mount() requires a static container (e.g. <div id='app' />) there, it seems that we just create a sub-node under the '#app' with id=$pageId (let's say pageId is unique) and then mount our Vue instance at it, after unmount a page, let's remove place-holder sub-node.

Comment: @MattiaDelFranco could you share your solution for this if you found it? I get similar requirement but I am not familiar with advanced features of vue js.